# Getting the value of a local Field at run time

Tags: c#, reflection, local, .net-assembly

I am really new to c# and I just want to know if it is possible to get the value of a locally declared field at runtime? Say for instance that ClassToTest in the example below can't be changed.

example:

```
public class ClassToTest {
  public void func() {
    int number = 25;
  }
}

Public class MyProgram {
  public static void Main() {
    ClassToTest instance = new ClassToTest();
    instance.func();
    // Can field "number" value be extracted here?
  }
}
```

I have been looking through reflection and other assembly related stuff but still no luck. Any suggestions will highly be appreciated.

Comment: No, that is not possible and there is no reason to do that. `number` is scoped to the method and not the class. Also you should start with posting code that can compile. Test it yourself to see if you can get it to run. If you want the value then return it  from the method or make a class/instance scoped property and set its value.

Comment: i have reduced the example to the simplest that it can get. Originally the program that I am working on is a lot bigger and complicated than this. And also I can't refactor the ClassToTest.

Comment: It is very simple. The method sets the value but as soon as it out of scope (ie. the method finishes running) the variable and its value is popped off the stack. There is no way to get that value. Also do not try to get the value, that is just **very** bad programming practice. You would be breaking encapsulation. If you are interested in that value then find a way to set it on the instance that knows about it OR return it OR write a new method that re-calculates it.

Comment: I was thinking maybe running the method on a separate thread. Then, do a Thread.sleep() or anything similar to stall it from closing. then, use reflection to get the value?

Comment: This won´t work as you still can´t access that variable, and even *if* it worked it was pure overkill.

Comment: No. You have 2 choices. 1. Refactor as I mentioned before. 2. Add a new method that recalculates that value and returns it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how functions work.

```
public class ClassToTest {
  public int func() {
    return 25;
  }
}

Public class MyProgram {
  public static void Main() {
    ClassToTest instance = new ClassToTest();
    int number = instance.func();
  }
}
```

Functions that return a value should have a return type (i.e. int), and a return (i.e. return 25;), then when int number = instance.func(); is ran, the func() method will return 25 and store it to int number

Answer (score 0):

You can´t access variables that are out of your current scope, be it another method or even just another switch-case. However there´s no reason to do this, you can do the same by setting a property within your method instead:

```
public class ClassToTest {
    public int Number { get; private set; }
    public void func() {
        this.Number = 25;
    }
}

Public class MyProgram {
    public static void Main() {
        ClassToTest instance = new ClassToTest();
        instance.func();
        var i = instance.Number;
    }
}
```

I also used a public getter for the property in combination with a private setter making it possible to change the `Number`-value from *inside* your class but not from the outside.

Another way as pointed by others is just to return the value from the `func`.

Comment: `public int Numer { get; private set; }` Little mistake in the name

Comment: As I have said in the comment above: "i have reduced the example to the simplest that it can get. Originally the program that I am working on is a lot bigger and complicated than this. And also I can't refactor the ClassToTest".

Comment: @AngeloCharl You *have* to change that class in order to get the value from the func or re-think your complete approach. You *can´t* access the variable because when leaving the scope (in your case the method) the variable doesn´t exist anymore.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't possible because something declared in a Body isn't accessible from the outer scope. Means that your variable is only avaiable inside your func()-Method. What you could do is return the value you need or declare a property.

```
public int Func()
{
  return 25;
}

public class MyProgram {
  public static void Main() {
    ClassToTest instance = new ClassToTest();
    int number = instance.func();
    //number will be 25
  }
}
```

With a Property this could work like this:

```
public class ClassToTest {

  public int Number{get{return 25;};private set;}
}

Public class MyProgram {
  public static void Main() {
    ClassToTest instance = new ClassToTest();
    int number = instance.Number;
  }
}
```

Using method or property is your decision. But you can think of it like:

"What does my object consists of" and "What can my object do".

For example a Car has Wheels. So represent a Wheel by a property. But a car can Move, so implement the movement as Method.